# WPF The machine.config file was not found?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I suddenly started getting this error after working on this project for a few days.

In my **MainWindow.xaml** :

[image]

The more specific location of the error in my **SidePanelView.xaml** (a user control) :

[image]

I am using a package (from Nuget) that uses this config file. If I go to that file location then the file is there so I'm not sure why it says its not found, and also I'm not sure why it ends up in that location either.

This error causes the SidePanelView user control to not displayer in the Designer for the MainWindow, which is fine because the app appears to run correctly and everything displays. The only problem I am having is with a strange Buttom command binding issue which I thought maybe could possibly be related to this issue since I don't know to what else ([WPF Button Command not firing, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059694)).

Does anybody have any ideas as to what is causing this issue, or should I just ignore it? Thanks

Comment: It actually looks like its trying to find the key `machineConfigFilename` in your `mydllname.dll.config` file. Can you verify that you have that file and that it includes a key that points to the machine.config file?

Comment: Maybe package is updated and you have to re-refence it (delete dll from project references and add it again)?

Comment: @RonBeyer I have the file but it does not contain they key. I have used this same package for a WinForm application, so I'm not sure why its raising an exception now. Why does it need the `machineConfigFilename` key? Or does it not?

Comment: @Sinatr I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Maybe some WPF-specific feature is requesting the key, but since it is complaining about it then I would guess its needed. Without knowing *what* package you are using, its hard to tell you why its complaining about it in this case and not in Winforms.

Comment: @Sinatr didn't work :( I'm not sure why its even looking in that file for the parameter `machineConfigFilename`...

Comment: Something has changed if that was working before. Try to get this package again. Try fresh project and if it works, try to find out why yours stops working: comment recent changes, temporarily removing files from project, etc.

Comment: @RonBeyer It seems the application runs smoothly for the most part despite this error. Do you think my problem I linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059694) would somehow be related? Or do you think I can solve that issue independent of this one which seemingly hasn't effected anything other than not seeing the user control in the Designer.

Comment: i think you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906964/why-does-my-usercontrol-not-display-in-the-designer